# display inline different elements in a div

Tags: html, css

```
<td>    <div class="Parent">
        <div class="willnotbedisplayed">some embed tag</div>//which will not show any html in UI
        <a class="image one">holds image</a>
        <a class="image two">holds image</a>
        <span class="hidden"></span>//will not display always hidden
        <input type="textbox"/>
    </div>
</td>
```

I have above html in a table's td, I want to display all these inline.
I tried many ways but I couldn't any work around please..............

Comment: `td div { display: inline }` ? What did you try?

Comment: i tried display: inline-block; by wrapping the inner elements with a div

Comment: Well, the rule I posted above would display all the `div`s inline. If that's not what you want, you have to provide a better explanation of your problem/desired outcome.

Comment: What CSS did you try in your _"many ways"_? `float:left;` would work, `display:inline` would work, `display:inline-block` (what you mentioned) would also work. Maybe you have some misunderstanding somewhere in your CSS, edit what you tried into your question.

Comment: as per my html structure above, I want to display the two anchors which will be images and input text box side by side. remaining div and span will not display any html in UI, will be hidden.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display all element inline you can try below jsfiddle code.

http://jsfiddle.net/murli2308/u7b83/2/

You have to add below CSS

```
td *{display:inline;}
```

If you table width is less then elements will move to the next line.. Can you please give the jsfiddle of your code.. or can you please post your all code Here....

Answer (score 1):

You can check the following [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4h6dD/2/)

```
.parent{
display:inline
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.Parent > * {display: inline;}
```

This will work, although the `*` css selector is not fast